# Given a right triangle, what is the length of the angle bisector to the circumcircle?

Tags: geometry

We have a right triangle ABC with right angle at C. If we draw the angle bisector at point C (the right angle), we will see that it hits the circumcircle at one other point.

How would we go about finding the distance between C and that point? This seems like a simple problem, maybe I can't think straight today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $\overline{CD}$ be the bisector, with $D$ on the circumcircle. Since $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BD}$ subtend inscribed angles of measure $45^\circ$, they subtend central angles of $90^\circ$. Thus, $\triangle AOD$ and $\triangle BOD$ are isosceles right triangles with hypotenuse $c \sqrt{2}/2 = c/\sqrt{2}$.

By [Ptolmey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem),

$$\begin{align}
|AB||CD| = |AC||BD| + |BC||AD| &\quad\to\quad
c\cdot|CD| = b\cdot\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}}+a\cdot\frac{c}{\sqrt{2}} \\[8pt]
&\quad\to\quad
|CD| = \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the bisector meets the circle at the point D and intersect AB at point P.

Two triangles CDB and CAP are similar.

Thus we have the relation $$ \frac {CB}{CP} = \frac {DB}{AP} =\frac {CD}{AC}$$

Thus we have $$ CD= \frac {AC.CB}{CP}$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]Draw a line from A paralel to CB, it intersect the circle on F. Extend the bisector of angle C (vertex C) to intersect the circle on G and previous line on E. Following relations can be considered:

$EC^2=2AC^2$  ⇒  $EC=AC\sqrt 2$

$EF=AC-CB$

$EF\times AC=EG\times EC$

⇒ $EG=\frac{(AC-CB)AC}{AC\sqrt 2}=\frac{AC-CB}{\sqrt 2}$

$CG=EC-EG=AC\sqrt 2-\frac{AC-CB}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{AC+CB}{\sqrt 2}$